# How to join three tables with multiple primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables as following

Table a (id,name) as primary key

Table b (id,name,country) as primary key,c_id as foreign key

Table c (id) as primary key, another column is type

I would like to select id,name,type from these tables, where country='CA'

MY database is MySQL, I wrote the SQL as following:

```
select n.activity_date,n.advertiser_id,c.type as type
from  a JOIN b as n
    on (a.id=b.id,a.name=b.name)
    JOIN c
    on n.c_id=c.id
where b.country='CA'
limit 10;
```

The error is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as n
on (a.activity_date=d.activity_date,a.advertiser_id=d.advertiser_id)
JOIN t' at line 2
```

Comment: `a.id=n.id,a.name=n.name` to `a.id=n.id AND a.name=n.name`

Comment: You've added an Alias to table b so either you take out the alias or change the alias of the fields on your `on` clause

Comment: @1nflktd Does not work. The error is `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as n
on (a.id=b.id AND a.name=b.name)`

Comment: @user3795071 change your `b` to `n`

Comment: @1nflktd Still same error.

Comment: @user3795071 You are using the real columns names, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use AND for multiple criteria joins, not a comma.

```
select n.activity_date,n.advertiser_id,c.type as type
from  a 
    JOIN b as n on a.id=n.id AND a.name=n.name
    JOIN c on n.c_id=c.id
where n.country='CA'
limit 10;
```

Comment: Don't forget about the alias n.

Comment: Does not work. The error is `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as n
on (a.id=b.id AND a.name=b.name)`
JO' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
select n.activity_date,n.advertiser_id,c.type as type
from  a JOIN b as n
    -- because of the alias name you've got to reference table b as n
    -- and you've omitted the AND operator
    on (a.id=n.id AND a.name=n.name)  
    JOIN c
    on n.c_id=c.id
where n.country='CA'  -- you've got to use n instead of b
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `on` is incorrect. You do not separate the clauses with `,`. You have to use boolean logic, which means `and` and `or`, e.g:

```
from  a JOIN b as n
    on (a.id=b.id AND a.name=b.name)
                  ^^^^---- no commas here
```

Comment: Does not work. The error is `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as n
on (a.id=b.id AND a.name=b.name)`